# Selenium how to click a button with hidden attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, hidden

I need to click on a button that is part of a grid menu. It show's the item price column in the grid, by default it is hidden.

```
<button type="button" class="ui-grid-menu-item" ng-click="itemAction($event, title)" ng-show="itemShown()" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-menu-item-active': active(), 'ui-grid-sr-only': (!focus &amp;&amp; screenReaderOnly) }" aria-pressed="" tabindex="0" ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" aria-hidden="true"><i ng-class="icon" aria-hidden="true" class="ui-grid-icon-ok">&nbsp;</i> Item Price</button>
```

I took an approach to first making it shown by setting aria-hidden="false".

```
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)(_chromeDriver);
        js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementByXPath('//*[@id='menuitem-5']/button').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false')");
```

But I'm getting javascript error.

```
javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)
```

I've checked this answer also

[Selenium EventFiringWebDriver JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52431550/selenium-eventfiringwebdriver-javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument)

But no solution yet.
How do I resolve it? Is my approach right or should I change.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to click the element directly

```
IWebElement element = _chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='menuitem-5']/button"));

js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I think the error you are seeing is from this line:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)(_chromeDriver);
```

change it to this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_chromeDriver);
```

Comment: it also gives the same error. javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Comment: I added to my answer

Comment: I separated finding the element from the javascript and edited my answer

Comment: This worked. Can you explain why it is not working when searching and action combined.?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I need to research that, too.